# Why do we need to use brackets while composing functions in haskell?

Tags: haskell, function-composition

Let say I have need to define the following function:

Identity = chr.ord

But the above line won't work, the correct way would be:

Identity = (chr.ord)

Haskell usually is quite a minimalist language, so using that extra brackets does not seem natural(to me).

Is anyone aware of the need for introducing the brackets. I can't remember where else we use the dot operator in haskell (other then  for decimals).

*Editing after comments from Nate/Daniel*

Both you are correct. My actual method was:

```
nextLetter a 
         | a /= 'z' = chr.ord a
         | a == 'z' = 'a'
```

Now I understand, in this case it will evaluate ord a and then try to evaluate chr.97, hence the error!

Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with omitting parentheses.  Can you edit your question, and add the error that you are getting?

Comment: I think he meant `identity x = chr.ord x`

Comment: That was quick, marking the answer by Daniel, as it helped uncover the mistake.

Comment: By the way, the standard way of omitting parens in this case is to write `chr . ord $ a`.

Comment: Or `chr $ ord a`. Matter of taste. The problem being obviously that `chr.ord x` is parsed as `chr.(ord x)`, not `(chr.ord) x`.

Comment: Another note of style, it's usually best to surround `.` with whitespace so as to not confuse function composition with OOP-style dispatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mistaken. When I write

```
import Data.Char
identity = chr.ord
```

in `test.hs` and load it in `ghci`, nothing goes wrong.